# How to Store Items to Cart when Clicking Elegant Plus number Button

Tags: java, android, firebase

i want to store items when clicking "+" button from  this recyclerview is in adapterclass . i want to store this to cart.

//if i click + number button then the item should go to the cart. please anyone help me.
i am retrieving all details from firebase. if anyone can help me please

```
public class ItemsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context applicationContext;
    List<Items> mItemsList;
    DataTransferInterface dtInterface;

    Feature feature;
    BestSell bestSell;
    Items items;

    FirebaseFirestore mStore;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;


    public ItemsRecyclerAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<Items> mItemsList, DataTransferInterface dtInterface) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.mItemsList = mItemsList;
        this.dtInterface = dtInterface;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext).inflate(R.layout.single_item_layout,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        holder.btn1.setRange(1, 10);
        holder.btn1.setOnClickListener((ElegantNumberButton.OnClickListener) view -> {
            String number = holder.btn1.getNumber();


        });
        holder.btn1.setOnValueChangeListener((view, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            Log.d("TAG", String.format("oldValue: %d   newValue: %d", oldValue, newValue));

            holder.qnt = newValue;

            Log.d("TAG", String.format("qnt %d   newValue: %d", holder.qnt, newValue));

            dtInterface.onSetValues(mItemsList,holder.qnt);


        });



        //all itms il maaruunath

        holder.mCost.setText(mItemsList.get(position).getPrice()+"AED");
        holder.mName.setText(mItemsList.get(position).getName());
        holder.mQuantity.setText(mItemsList.get(position).getQuantity());
        holder.mCountry.setText(mItemsList.get(position).getCountry());
        if (!(applicationContext instanceof HomeActivity)){
            Glide.with(applicationContext).load(mItemsList.get(position).getImg_url()).into(holder.mItemImage);

        }else {
                holder.mItemImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.mItemImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(applicationContext, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("detail",mItemsList.get(position));

                applicationContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        holder.go_to_details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(applicationContext, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("detail",mItemsList.get(position));

                intent.putExtra("quantity",holder.qnt);
                applicationContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.mName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(applicationContext, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("detail",mItemsList.get(position));
                applicationContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItemsList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView mItemImage;
        private TextView mCost;
        private TextView mName;
        private TextView mCountry;
        private TextView mQuantity;
        private ImageView go_to_details;


        public ElegantNumberButton btn1;
        int qnt =1;





        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mItemImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            mCost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_cost);
            mName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_nam);
            mCountry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_country);
            mQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);

            go_to_details = itemView.findViewById(R.id.go_to_detail);

            btn1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_button);


        }

    }
    public interface DataTransferInterface {
        public void onSetValues(List<Items> mItemList, int al);
    }
```

[image]

**//if i click + number button then the item should go to the cart. please anyone help me.
i am retrieving all details from firebase. if anyone can help me please**

Comment: Edit your question with details of code as well.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: dtInterface.onSetValues(mItemsList,holder.qnt);
i need to pass the items via interface, atleast